# pymouse not running with opencv in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision

[image]Its a simple code that i was testing

When i use cv2.imshow and subsequently waitkey() of opencv the pymouse module stops working and doesnt change mouse's co-ordinates but when i comment out the imshow and waitkey() m.move works properly here is my code and also a screenshot

```
import cv2
from pymouse import PyMouse

m = PyMouse()

img = cv2.imread("123.jpg")

cv2.imshow("img", img)![enter image description here][2]
cv2.waitKey(0)

m.move(0,0)

print "lastline"
```

the "lastline" never gets printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official documentation of OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html):

> The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely (when \texttt{delay}\leq 0 ) or for delay milliseconds, when it is positive.

So when you put in your code:

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It waits indefinitely for a user input i.e. if you don't type something the following lines won't be executed (that's why when you comment out the line the move action is executed)

Comment: oh okay. don't know how i missed such a trivial thing....anyways thanks for your help

Comment: No biggie, don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped you :)